# How to enable button when Datagrid changes?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, datagrid

How can I enable a button when any of the data inside a Datagrid changes?

```
    <DataGrid x:Name="GlobalShortcutsDataGrid" 
            ItemsSource="{Binding GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
            AutoGenerateColumns="False">

        <DataGrid.Columns >
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Name" Binding="{Binding ShortcutName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Path" Binding="{Binding FilePath}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>

    <Button x:Name="buttonSave" IsEnabled="False"
            Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
            Content="Save Edits">

        <Button.Style>
            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Button}" BasedOn="{StaticResource {x:Type Button}}">
                <Style.Triggers>
                    // I'm not sure how to check for datagrid changes here
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </Button.Style>
    </Button>
```

Comment: What does change? Background color, sorting, data, number of columns?

Comment: Oops, the data (text) inside the datagrid.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to do these changes:

**XAML**

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GlobalShortcutsDataGrid" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
        AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Name" Binding="{Binding ShortcutName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Path" Binding="{Binding FilePath}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button x:Name="buttonSave" IsEnabled="{Binding IsButtonSaveEnabled}"
        Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
        Content="Save Edits"/>
```

**YourVM**

Create the new bool property:

```
public bool IsButtonSaveEnabled
   {
     get
       {
         return yourLogicToBeEnabled;
       }
   }
```

then in your `FilePath` or `ShortcutName` set (I don't know which one is used to change the status of the button) just raise the change of `IsButtonSaveEnabled`.

---

***Edit***: Changed the XAML because I thought you wanted to hide it not to change the enable state. Just remove the converter.

---

Edit: To solve your scenario I'd create a class like this:

```
public class YourParentVMDataSource
{
    private YourParentVM yourParentVM;
    private GlobalShortcutsVM globalShorcutsVM;

    public YourParentVMDataSource(GlobalShortcutsVM globalShortcutsVm, YourParentVM yourParentVM)
    {
        this.globalShorcutsVM = globalShortcutsVm;
        this.yourParentVM = yourParentVM;
    }

    public void CreateDataSource()
    {
        this.globalShorcutsVM.Model.PropertyChanged += this.OnGlobalShortcutsModelPropertyChanged
    }

    private void OnGlobalShortcutsModelPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case "ShortcutName":
                this.yourParentVM.RaisePropertyChanged("IsButtonSaveEnabled");
                break;
            case "FilePath":
                this.yourParentVM.RaisePropertyChanged("IsButtonSaveEnabled");
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Where `yourParentVM` is your "main" VM and `GlobalShortcutsVM` is the VM I supposed you use to fill the `DataGrid` (you should have an `ObservableCollection<GlobalShortcutsVM> GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection`)

Everytime something changes in your GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection Model it will raise the event and you handle it. In the handler you raise the property of the parent VM.

You should create this new class and call to the `CreateDataSource` method after you create you "main" VM.

Comment: @ Juan Carlos - Hmm, so this can not be done in XAML? I'm not sure if your suggestion would work since `FilePath` or `ShortcutName` are not part the `ViewModel` of that `View`, they're part of a `model` consumed by `GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection`. Thanks.

Comment: In that case I suggest you to create a behavior and apply it to your `DataGrid` and in its celleditingend ( I think that's the name of the action :S ) you could change the button enable status. I'll try to edit my answer with that :D

Comment: @fs_tigre But you could also implement INotifyPropertyChanged for your Model.

Comment: @Rekshino I guess his VM`s Model is not the same one as his DataGrid VM's Model. In that case he should create a DataSource with the parent VM, the DataGrid VM and the DataGrid Model

Comment: @JuanCarlosRodriguez But it is possible to subscribe in ViewModel to the PropertyChanged events of model.

Comment: @Rekshino Hmm, maybe with `RaisePropertyChanged()` and `Messenger` from MVVM Light, I will try sending a message every time the model changes, I think that's a good idea.

Comment: @Rekshino Ofc you can but `GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection` should be an 
 ObservableCollection<GlobalShortcutVM> which should have a different Model from the "parent" VM. Hence, you need to create a class that has the "parent" VM and the "GlobalShortcutVM" which need to be created after the VMs declaration. There, you attach to your GlobalShortcutVM.Model.OnPropertyChanged and update the IsButtonSaveEnabled

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to achieve it. The preferred way is to do it in ViewModel and bind to the some ViewModel property `IsSaveEnabled`.

Another way to handle `CellEditEnding` event for your `DataGrid`.

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GlobalShortcutsDataGrid" CellEditEnding="dataGrid_CellEditEnding"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">

    <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Name" Binding="{Binding ShortcutName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Path" Binding="{Binding FilePath}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button x:Name="buttonSave" IsEnabled="False"
    Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
    Content="Save Edits">
</Button>
```

Code behind:

```
private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
{
    var tb = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
    var bindingIsDirty = tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).IsDirty;
    buttonSave.IsEnabled |= (bindingIsDirty && e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit);
}
```

You could also move the code behind functionality to a behavior with some dependency property IsDirty and bind Button.IsEnabled to this property:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="GlobalShortcutsDataGrid"
    ItemsSource="{Binding GlobalShortcutsObservableCollection}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRow}"
    AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                <local:DataGridChangedBehavior IsDataGridChanged="{Binding Path=IsEnabled, ElementName=buttonSave}"/>
            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
            <DataGrid.Columns >
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Name" Binding="{Binding ShortcutName}"></DataGridTextColumn>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="Shortcut Path" Binding="{Binding FilePath}"></DataGridTextColumn>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>

<Button x:Name="buttonSave" IsEnabled="False"
    Command="{Binding SaveCommand}"
    Content="Save Edits">
</Button>


public class DataGridChangedBehavior: Behavior<DataGrid>
{
    public bool IsDataGridChanged
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDataGridChangedProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsDataGridChangedProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDataGridChangedProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsDataGridChanged", typeof(bool), typeof(DataGridChangedBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
        base.OnAttached();
        AssociatedObject.CellEditEnding += dataGrid_CellEditEnding;
    }

    protected override void OnDetaching()
    {
        AssociatedObject.CellEditEnding -= dataGrid_CellEditEnding;
        base.OnDetaching();
    }

    private void dataGrid_CellEditEnding(object sender, DataGridCellEditEndingEventArgs e)
    {
        var tb = e.EditingElement as TextBox;
        var bindingIsDirty = tb.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).IsDirty;
        IsDataGridChanged |= (bindingIsDirty && e.EditAction == DataGridEditAction.Commit);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will use code behind if I cannot figure out how to do it with MVVM or XAML.